# How to detect Visual C++ 2013 redistributable package

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013

How can I detect when "Visual C++ 2013 redistributable" is installed?

The following c++ code detects the 2010 redist correctly:

```
    // Visual C++ 2010 Redist detection...
    INSTALLSTATE state = pMsiProc( _T("{F0C3E5D1-1ADE-321E-8167-68EF0DE699A5}") );
    if(state == INSTALLSTATE_DEFAULT)
    {
        // Visual C++ 2010 redist installed.
    }
```

I was hoping to use the same sort of code for 2013 redist, but the INSTALLSTATE always returns INSTALLSTATE_DEFAULT whether the package is installed or not.  Anyone know why?

```
    // call MsiQueryProductStateW...
    INSTALLSTATE state = pMsiProc(_T("{13A4EE12-23EA-3371-91EEEFB36DDFFF3E}"));
    // 
    if ((state == INSTALLSTATE_DEFAULT || state == INSTALLSTATE_LOCAL) 
    {
        // 2013 redist is installed.
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you on a x86 architecture? If not, the code is different: https://allthingsconfigmgr.wordpress.com/2013/12/17/visual-c-redistributables-made-simple/

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative, you can enumerate the registry looking at the "*Displayname*" key for the following tokens: 'Microsoft', 'Visual', 'C++', 'Redistributable'.  You can use the following to determine if the sub-key is what you're after...

```
//  search for valid tokens to indicate this is a redistributable.
resToken = name.Tokenize (_T(" "), curPos);
while (resToken != _T(""))
    {
    if (resToken == _T("Microsoft"))
        tokenCount |= 0x01;
    if (resToken == _T("Visual"))
        tokenCount |= 0x02;
    if (resToken == _T("C++"))
        tokenCount |= 0x04;
    if (resToken == _T("Redistributable"))
        tokenCount |= 0x08;
    resToken = name.Tokenize (_T(" "), curPos);
    }

//  check for matching tokens in the Display Name.
if (tokenCount == 0x0f)
    {
```

Simply start your search at "**SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall**" and enumerate all of the sub-keys for the above values.  You would also need to check both the 32 and 64 bit hives.